# WPF Navigation using MVVM. Load different user controls to content control on main window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

I have a MainWIndow with content control. I have several user controls. I can load the first user control to the main window content control. Now this user control has several UI controls. On clicking on the button I want to load another user control to the Main Window content control. If clicked on another UI element may be a different user control has to be loaded to content control. How can I build this navigation using MVVM?

The main window itself has several buttons and a content control, I can set the content by binding to the viewmodel. But how to implemtn navigation when the parent window has just the content control and actions on each user control has to load entirely different user control with a different set of actions.?

Comment: To be clear, that you are saying "load user control" is the same as "show it"?